# RegisterStartupScript in ButtonClick event of UserControl

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a usercontrol with a form and a button. In the code behind of the button's click event, I save the data from the form to the database.  After the save is successfully saved, I'd like to pop up a javascript alert. I've tried the following:

```
Control Caller = this;
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Caller, Caller.GetType(), " ", 
   @"<script language=javascript>alert('Asset successfully saved');</script>", true);
```

This doesn't work. What am I doing wrong, or even how do I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have set the addScriptTags to true and you are also trying to add your own script tags in the js code.  Set this value to false and try again or remove the script block tags in your js.  You can find out more details on [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Piecing together other's code and I missed that. Not sure why, but "Control Caller = this;" works for one of my user controls but "Control Caller = Page;" works for another.